# Compiling OCCI on "Oracle linux"

Tags: c++, linux, oracle

I am trying to develop some app using oracle with OCCI in c++. I installed "oracle linux" and oracle db 12c successfully. I am assuming OCCI is included db as its one of parts so I just tried to compile following code as following further down.

```
g++ -std=c++11 one.cc -o mm
```

one.cc

```
#include <occi.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
return 0;}
```

and the compilation result is:

```
fatal error: occi.h: no such file or dir..
```

alright, what should I do? am I forgetting something else? or anyother flags so that link? please provide me any thing you think an answer.
tnx

Comment: Check you have occi.h somewhere. If you have is the folder in the search path that the compiler uses? (I'm not familiar with g++)

Answer (score 0):

---

> occi.h: no such file

`occi.h` is provided by e.g. ``oracle-instantclient-devel´´

Available version are 10.2 and 11.2, see http://rpm.pbone.net : CentOS6, RHEL7, Fedora 17.. 18. Or ask Oracle for other choices.

---

---